# Practical example of difference between p(y|x) and p(x|y)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, generative-models, bayesian

I've been reading about the difference between generative models and discriminative models. I know that for generative models we learn the joint probability p(x,y) or just p(x|y) and p(y). For a new data point we can then ask: "what is the probability for a new data point x to have label 1?", so we calculate p(y=1|x) using bayes rule. For discriminative models we learn a conditional probability p(y|x). In the end, both learn p(y|x).

My question is: can anyone give a practical example (with some fake datapoints) that show why generative models calculate p(x, y) and why discriminative models calculate p(y|x)? What is the practical difference? I keep seeing drawings like:

[image]

... from which I understand that discriminative models separate the data into classes, and generative models learn the distribution of the classes. But, how does this relate to p(x, y) and p(y|x)?

Comment: [I think this video should provide an example.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=oTtow2Ui8vg)

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12421/250483